# grep file1 to file2 without changing order

Tags: awk, grep

```
cat file1
2   
5  
1  
6 

cat file2 
5 A  
2 B  
6 C  
1 D
```

Output file wanted is:

```
2 B  
5 A  
1 D  
6 C
```

I tried this:

```
grep -Ff file1 file2 > output
```

However, the output showed like this:

```
1 D  
2 B  
5 A  
6 C
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$0; next} $1 in a{print a[$1]}' file2 file1

2 B
5 A
1 D
6 C
```

without `awk` is little tricky

```
$ join -12 <(nl file1 | sort -k2) <(sort file2) | sort -k2n | cut -d' ' -f2 --complement
```

Comment: I tried awk but doesn't seem to work in my PC. Any other idea or grep code?

Comment: `grep` won't do, check the `join` version.  what does **"doesn't seem to work"** mean?  Fails? Gives a wrong output?  `awk` not found?  Did you verify with the sample data you posted?

Comment: I don't understand, you don't want keys to match exactly?  What happens there are multiple matches then?  Example data you post should be representative of your real case, otherwise it's difficult (impossible?) to guess what you need.

Comment: yes, I need it to print multiple matches. Any match starts with 1 or 2 etc.

Comment: OK. I solved it. Thank you. We just need to use awk with separator F to ignore whatever after ".".